# How to escape smart quote in French characters while displaying on JSP

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, internationalization

Currently, our application supports i18n.
We have one property file for each Locale.
For English, we were able to successfully display the placeholder defined in the property file.

### Problem

When we change the Locale / Language settings in the application from English to French we were unable to replace the placeholder.
Placeholder - String Date - This is being successfully returned from the controller but still we couldn't replace on the UI page.

This is because the complete value for the key specified in the JSP is not being rendered properly for French Locale & as a  result placeholder is not being replaced.

The special character with which we are facing issue is smart quote (d'essai)
Unicode for this character: U+00B4

We have tried placing UTF-8 encoding in the JSP page using Meta & Page directives but still, it didn't resolve the issue.

Any help is highly appreciated.

### My Code Snippet

```
<fmt:message bundle="${myBundle}" key="myKey"><fmt:param value="${nextDateInString}"/></fmt:message>
```

Votre période d’essai gratuit prend fin le {0}

As you can see {0} is not getting replaced dynamically for French locale whereas for English it is working as expected.

Tried using StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavascript(myMessageFromProperties)
also did not help

Comment: Yes Karpak ! It's in JSP!


<fmt:message bundle="${myBundle}" key="myMessageKey"><fmt:param value="${paramToBeReplaced"/></fmt:message>

Value in French properties file

Votre période d’essai gratuit prend fin le {0}

Comment: are you missing the closing curly brace in your original code here "${paramToBeReplaced}"?

Comment: what has this to do with javascript?

Comment: @Traktor53 : My thought was to call StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavascript() to see if any special characters can be escaped.

Comment: You can escape  '´' as `&#x00b4;` in HTML or `\u00b4` within javascript strings - if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The single quote is a special character in MessageFormat-Strings used to quote text, which the is then not processed. See Java API for [MessageFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html).

You need two single quotes to escape it and display one single quote.